# Interactivity on WebGL Canvas - PIXI + D3

Tags: d3.js, canvas, webgl, interactive, pixi.js

I have a data visualisation with pixi.js and d3 - a proof of concept. It should run on WebGL canvas to enable custom shaders.
Current state can be viewed at https://codepen.io/stopyransky/full/vrMxKQ/

The goal is to have following interactivity features:

- clicking and dragging sprite to set it's new location
- panning
- zooming vis to screen (scaling)

I am stuck on panning and zooming, I have tried below solution and events are recognized properly but I am unable to move the graph.

```
d3.select(app.view)
  .call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 8])
    .on("zoom", function zoomed() {
      transform = d3.event.transform;
      if(!globalDragging) updateSimulationOnZoom();
    })
  );

function updateSimulationOnZoom() {
  if(d3.event.sourceEvent.type === 'wheel') {
   console.log('zooming')
  }
  if(d3.event.sourceEvent.type === 'mousemove') {
    console.log("paning");

    data.sprites.forEach(sprite => {
    sprite.fx += transform.x
    sprite.fy += transform.y
  })
 }
}
```

How to implement properly d3 zoom and pan on webgl canvas in this situation?

Comment: I kinda found the solution for that but it does not include d3.zoom tool. There is [pixi-viewport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixi-viewport) package available which is a PIXI.Container and handles interactions like dragging and zooming on scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question to close this topic - as per my comment:

There is clean way to achieve zooming and panning interactivity with [pixi-viewport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixi-viewport). It blends nicely with pixi application - acts as stage to which graphics/sprites can be added.